# For Loop generate URL didn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, laravel

I want to write `{{ url('character/c1') }}` to be `localhost:8000/character/c1` but it didn't work inside JavaScript function.

It resulting the exact `localhost:8000/{{ url('character/c1') }}` link instead.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var characters = [
      "geer",
      "daar",
      "geet",
      "geen"
    ]

    var character = "";
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
      character += "<a href=\"\{\{ url('character/c" + i + "') \}\}\"><li></li>" + "</a>";
    }

    document.getElementById('characters').innerHTML = character;
</script>

<ul id="characters"></ul>
```

Comment: Check my answer. Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your for loop as this,

```
var url = {{ url('character') }};
for (i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
  character += '<a href="' + url + '/c' + i + '"><li></li></a>';
}
```

Comment: You need to debug your js code in the browser console. Check where fails.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[Learn More]

the variable turns to be `var url = http://localhost:8000/character;`

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before the for loop

```
var url = window.location; // To get current window url
var url = "<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>" + ":<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ?>"; // To get your server name with Port
```

Then inside the for loop modify the line like this.

```
character += "<a href=\"\{\{" +  url + "('character/c" + i + "') \}\}\"><li><img src=\"character/list/c" + i +  "/icon.png\"></li>" + "</a>";
```

window.location will give you current url. Ofcourse, if you want your server name only. You can take the php option.

Cheers. Happy coding.

Comment: here's what I got: `localhost:8000/character/{{127.0.0.1:8000('character/c1') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I have figure it out myself.
It's because `c1` is inside a route `get(/character/{id})`

```
for (i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
  character += '<a href="c' + i + '"><li></li></a>';
}
```